# How to write test driven programming in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, express, serverside-javascript

Recently I got introduced to node.js and packages like express, mongodb and ejs. I have few questions :

As a learning purpose, I have created a [github repo of user management](https://github.com/justin-john/node-user-management) which uses express, mongodb and ejs. I have all my functions in [routes/users.js](https://github.com/justin-john/node-user-management/blob/master/routes/users.js)  file. I need to write test cases all these functions. How to create a  test driven programming with this example?

In my [routes](https://github.com/justin-john/node-user-management/blob/master/app.js#L25-L26) in `app.js` file.

```
app.get('/login', user.login);
app.post('/login', user.loginSubmit);
```

I need to write different routes to login page renders and submit etc. If there are some ajax request also, then we have lots of routes in `app.js` file when considering to routes of a single page. Is it like that or need to change my structure?

Comment: isnt express bundled with tests ? you could just look at the repo and see if there are some test utilities you can use or recycle.

Comment: @mpm How to run tests in express? In express test some functions `describe`, `test` etc are there. From where we can find docs and usage of these functions?

Comment: look for either mocha or jasmine but i guess express creator used mocha ,since he created it too.

Comment: may be you try [vows](http://vowsjs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/), it's from the same guy of expressjs.
It supports test coverage for you code, hooks before, after, each and of course it supports async code.

I use it in combination with should.js or even chai.js

A test in mocha looks like, the code is from my own test where I'm using superagent, in order to make requests.

```
it('requests a permission with valid ticket', function (done){
        agent
            .post(route.server + '/preq')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + ACCESSTOKEN)
            .send({ticket: TICKET})
            .end(function (req,res) {

                res.should.have.property('statusCode').that.equals(201);
                var location = .....
                res.headers.should.have.property('location').that.is.equal(location);
                done();
            });
    })
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of mocha integration with my [registerUser](https://github.com/justin-john/node-user-management/blob/master/routes/users.js#L107-L146) function?

Comment: I have install `mocha` by `npm install mocha` and created a file `test/test.js`. I haved copied the all code from gist to `test.js` and tried with command `make test` in root,  but receives a message in shell as `make: Nothing to be done for \`test'.` and when entering same command with `test` folder as root gives another message `make: *** No rule to make target \`test'.  Stop.` How could we run the test file?

Comment: you could execute from a Makefile or from npm scripts variable, but the easiest way is `mocha test/ -R spec`

Comment: I have changed **post(route.signup)** in gist example  to **post(route.registerUser)** . The  **var route = require('../routes/users')** is already defined.

Every time I am getting an error as

   `â¤

   â 1 of 3 tests failed:

   1) testing user "before all" hook:
      Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
       at null.<anonymous> (/home/justin/www/NodeUserManagement/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:167:14)
       at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:100:19)
       at process._makeCallback (node.js:248:20)


 make: *** [test] Error 1`

How to correct this error?